# HTML Javascript "Load more" button through javascript

Tags: jquery, ms-access, vbscript, asp-classic, adodb

I am trying to make a load more button to get more records from a Microsoft access database connection.

I am using HTML coding.  Here is what I have to get the first 10 records

```vb
<tr>
  <td>
    <%
    While ((Repeat1__index < 10) AND (NOT rsArticle.EOF))
    %>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table>
        <tr>
          <td><h3><%=(rsArticle.Fields.Item("Title").Value)%></h3></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <p><%=(rsArticle.Fields.Item("Summery").Value)%></p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <%
       Repeat1__index=Repeat1__index+1
       Repeat1__numRows=Repeat1__numRows-1
       rsArticle.MoveNext()
    Wend
    %>
  </td>
</tr>
```

as you can see the `Repeat1__index < 10` makes it only show the first ten records.

I would like to incorporate a "load more" button that will allow me to +10 records.

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb The OP is using [tag:asp-classic] not [tag:jsp] or [tag:java-ee], so I'm not sure how this is relevant?

Comment: You are right. Deleting my first comment.

Comment: Read-up on AJAX techniques. There is a client-side component as well as a server-side component to this. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030343/query-database-with-ajax-and-classic-asp