# Getting Text From Website using classic asp

Tags: asp-classic

I want to crawl this http://www.dollar2rupee.net/ website using asp and get data in this format http://dashboard.communicate2-apps.com/dollar2rupee/Index.aspx

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can crawl a website using HTTP Requests: [HTTP GET Request, ASP - I'm lost!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885170/http-get-request-asp-im-lost)

What you do with the data once you crawl the site however, is completely up to you.  You would probably need to go through the response text using [`Split()`](http://www.ezineasp.net/post/ASP-Vbscript-Split-String-into-Array-Examples.aspx),[`Instr()`](http://www.ezineasp.net/post/ASP-Vbscript-InStr-String-Function-Syntax.aspx),[`Mid()`](http://www.ezineasp.net/post/ASP-Vbscript-Mid-String-Function.aspx) functions to extract certain data from it.

Comment: What is not so useful?

Comment: but not in correct format its cmg like 100 - 299960.40 - 999960.590 - 120000060.250 - 100060.3325 - 999960.2525 - 999960.10

Comment: @user3816325 we're not going to write it for you - you need to do the horse work yourself and then come to us with problems, not for a solution; that's not what S.O is all about. In the meantime, [this may also be useful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030343/query-database-with-ajax-and-classic-asp) to you.

Comment: @user3816325 With an attitude like that I'll be surprised if anyone wants to help you. ZeeTee has provided you a sound example of how you can crawl and links to more information you could have found yourself, if that's not enough...tough. Maybe adjust your attitude if you want people to help you, like Paul said though, we are not going to do it for you that isn't what SO is all about.

Comment: @user3816325 See [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) particularly point 3. ***"Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."***.

Comment: Sorry guys i was not mean to be rude in anyway

Comment: 3 100 - 299960.40 - 999960.460 - 120000060.250 - 100060.2425 - 999960.2525 - 999960.10

4 3000 - 699960.4  1200001 - 999999960.21001 - 300060.27    

5 7000 - 899960.4    3001 - 500060.30    

6 9000 - 1000060.4    5001 - 800060.33    

7      8001 - 1000060.36        3-7 is line no which i got so can any one help to get in tabular form all this info

Comment: I suggest you post a new question about this, since it's out of the scope of the op